# CSS - Text moves when hovering

Tags: html, css, hover, move

I've been at this for about an hour now, and cant seem to grip it.
Everytime I hover over this text (I'm wanting to put a background color for it to hover), the text moves, along with the bgcolor. 
Here is what I got:

```
        #innerheader ul {
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #innerheader li {
            display:block;
            float:left;
            height:25px;
            margin:0 2px;
            padding:15px 10px 0 10px;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:10px;
            text-transform:uppercase;
        }

        #innerheader li a, 
        #innerheader li a:link, 
        #innerheader li a:visited, 
        #innerheader li a:active {
            color:#FFFFFF;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        #innerheader li a:hover {
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px
        }
```

Comment: Use a CSS reset to save you more troubles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the padding in the hover declaration. Or simply move the padding to the anchor before the hover state, like the code below.

The reason the text is moving is there is no padding on the anchor, then when you hover, there's padding.

```
#innerheader li a, 
    #innerheader li a:link, 
    #innerheader li a:visited, 
    #innerheader li a:active {
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #innerheader li a:hover {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: why doesn't the text in the example below (the 3rd example) move with the hover, then? I tried something similar and my text moves. https://codepen.io/Calloumi/pen/vndlH

Answer (score 1):

It's because of padding. Remove it then it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of padding, that is what is causing it to move.

Answer (score 0):

It's moving because you are changing the padding in the hover block. Remove that and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you're putting padding on the li a:hover! Of course it's going to shift the text. To fix this you need to define the width and height and reduce them by the padding amount on hover. OR move the padding to the non hover state.

Comment: Hi Kai: why doesn't the text in the example below (the 3rd example) move with the hover, then? I tried something similar and my text moves.  codepen.io/Calloumi/pen/vndlH